# What database type should I define CUSIP as?

Tags: sql, sql-server, finance

If [CUSIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusip) is defined as

> A CUSIP is a 9-character alphanumeric code which identifies a North American financial security for the purposes of facilitating clearing and settlement of trades.

then what type should I set it as in my SQL Server database? Are there any considerations I need to take into account?

Comment: our systems use `varchar(9)` on the `CUSIP` field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's a fixed-length, right? Always 9 characters - never more, never less?

In that case, I'd use **`CHAR(9)`** since using a `VARCHAR` with a variable-length doesn't benefit you anything, and it carries some overhead. And since it's a North American standard, I doubt you'll have to enter Cyrillic, Arab, Hebrew or Far Eastern characters, so `CHAR` (non-Unicode, 1 byte per character) should be sufficient.

The fact that it's an *alphanumeric code* rules out all the numerical datatypes right away.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest consideration to take into place is that CUSIPS can, and do, change. I'd store the cusip as char(9), but be certain to take into account that they might change so not make the mistake of making them a unique key in your database.